# using R to track and remove duplicated sets

Tags: r, dataframe

I have raw dataset (metering data). Meter data are duplicated because it is copied along when Group name, Reading Client ID or Reading short name is present in database. Unfortunately it is different for each Meter ID - in some cases there will be none duplicates, two or even three times the same data. As a help in last column each data has its timestamp.

Problem:
I want to scan only for Meter ID and discard the copy when same data is copied for Group name or Reading Client ID or Reading Short Name leave only one set of data. Example below. I have commented lines when new duplicate starts.

What I have tried: duplicate function or following:

```
    df %>% 
  distinct(Meter.ID, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  {. ->> df2 }
```

My current methods are "too" selective and not universal. I have a difficulty approaching a problem with universal solution. **Best would be to use timestamp which is re-starting every time data is copied.**

**DATA sample**
{

```
"Meter ID","Group name","Reading Client ID","Reading Short Name",Reading,"Reading timestamp",Reading2
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580597999," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580594400," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580590800," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580587200," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580583600," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580580000," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580576400," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580572800," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580569200," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580565600," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580562000," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580558400," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580554800," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580551200," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580547600," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580544000," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580540400," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580536800," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580533200," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580529600," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580526000," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580522400," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580518800," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580515200," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580597999," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580594400," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580590800," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580587200," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580583600," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580580000," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580576400," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580572800," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580569200," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580565600," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580562000," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580558400," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580554800," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580551200," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580547600," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580544000," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580540400," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580536800," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580533200," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580529600," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580526000," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580522400," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580518800," - "
204,0100G,199,06865,90.436,1580515200," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580597999," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580594400," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580590800," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580587200," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580583600," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580580000," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580576400," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580572800," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580569200," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580565600," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580562000," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580558400," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580554800," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580551200," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580547600," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580544000," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580540400," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580536800," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580533200," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580529600," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580526000," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580522400," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580518800," - "
204,"0100G test2",199,06865,90.436,1580515200," - "
```

## Desired effect after processing:

```
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580597999," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580594400," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580590800," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580587200," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580583600," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580580000," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580576400," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580572800," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580569200," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580565600," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580562000," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580558400," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580554800," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580551200," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580547600," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580544000," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580540400," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580536800," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580533200," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580529600," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580526000," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580522400," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580518800," - "
204,"Strefa XX Pomorzany Kępa",199,06865,90.436,1580515200," - "
```

Comment: I can think of a solution, but how should the code decide on which of the three duplicates should be selected? This will matter for the Group Name column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on `dplyr` assuming OP wants to keep the first instance of the duplicated rows. 
I assume that the data is stored in a csv file names `Rtmp.csv`.

```
## Read the data
readr::read_csv("Rtmp.csv") %>% 
## Clean column names to remove spaces
janitor::clean_names() %>% 
## Remove duplicates
distinct(meter_id, reading_client_id, reading_timestamp, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just filter out rows using the `duplicated` function. It's not necessary for this dataset, but you probably want to order the data by group name to drop duplicated. Not duplicated will keep the first instance of the duplicated column.

```
df2 <- df2[order(df[['Group name']], decreasing=TRUE),]
df <- df2[!duplicated(df[["Reading timestamp"]]),]
```